# Calculate Returns of xts object with multiple columns

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

What is the most straight forward way to calculate the returns of an (n x m) xts object?

When I feed an (n x m) xts object `mxts` into the `quantmod` function `dailyReturn`, the return value is an (n x 1) vector, representing the returns of the first column. What I am looking for is a way to generate an (n x m) xts object containing the respective return vector for each column of `mxts`.

I have tried to work with some of the apply functions, such as

```
lapply(mxts,dailyReturn)
```

but the returns always had the wrong type and lost their labeling (`dailyReturn` changes the value of the `colnames` vector to "daily.returns").

Is there an easy, non-hacky way to achieve this? Am I maybe using a wrong function for this problem?

Comment: I prefer Joshua's `TTR::ROC`, but try this `do.call(cbind, lapply(mxts, dailyReturn))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ROC` function in the TTR package will do this, but you can easily do the calculation yourself using `lag` (which is what `ROC` does internally).

```
R> require(quantmod)  # loads TTR
R> getSymbols("SPY")
R> head(ROC(OHLC(SPY)))
                SPY.Open      SPY.High       SPY.Low     SPY.Close
2007-01-03            NA            NA            NA            NA
2007-01-04 -0.0071963059 -5.686021e-03  0.0002845153  0.0021198425
2007-01-05  0.0007078143 -4.586355e-03 -0.0016370693 -0.0080082636
2007-01-08 -0.0036151023  7.071886e-05 -0.0009264869  0.0046143553
2007-01-09  0.0034735795  1.342709e-03  0.0010689472 -0.0008502799
2007-01-10 -0.0051793368 -2.118869e-04 -0.0007125045  0.0033261416
```

Comment: note that `ROC` calculates log returns by default, but can be called with `type='discrete'` to give the same results as `dailyReturn`